# Taking the limit of the bounds of an integral

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that

$$\lim_{{\Delta \omega}\rightarrow 0^+} \int_{-\pi/\Delta \omega}^{\pi/\Delta \omega} f(\Delta \omega, t) dt = \lim_{{\Delta \omega}\rightarrow 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\Delta \omega, t) dt\label{eq:1}$$

Now, I know the composite limit theorem, which states that:

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow M} f(u) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x)) $$ Given that the following holds:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = M , \hspace{5mm} \lim_{u\rightarrow M} f(u) = f(M).$$

One can also derive the following property:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \left[ f(x) g(x) \right] = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \left[ K g(x) \right]  $$

Given that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = K, \hspace{5mm} \lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = L.$$

Is it possible to prove the first equality using these two limit theorems? I'm having doubts about applying the composite limit theorem, as $\int_{-\pi/\Delta \omega}^{\pi/\Delta \omega} f(\Delta \omega, t) dt$ is a functional and not a function. Does there exist an equivalent composite limit theorem for functionals?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with rigorous proofs, but it seems like it would be enough to note that $\lim_{\Delta\omega\to0^+} \pi/\Delta\omega=\infty$, and then to apply the first theorem, where $M=\infty$, $a=0^+$, and $g(x)=\pi/x$.

Comment: Yes, But I don't have a proof that this is allowed. As stated, this would require that the first theorem is applicable to functionals as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should impose some conditions on $f$.

For example, define $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ by $f(\Delta w, t)= \Delta w\exp\left(-(\Delta w)^2 t^2 \right)   $.

Then for $\Delta w >0 $\begin{align} \int_{-\pi/\Delta w}^{\pi/\Delta w}f(\Delta w, t) dt &= \Delta w\int_{-\pi/\Delta w}^{\pi/\Delta w}\exp \left( -(\Delta w)^2 t^2 \right)dt \\ &= \Delta w\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp\left(-s^2\right)\frac{1}{\Delta w}ds \\&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp\left(-s^2\right)ds\end{align}
Here change of variables $s=(\Delta w)t$ is used.

On the other hand, \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta w, t) dt &= \Delta w\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp \left( -(\Delta w)^2 t^2 \right)dt \\ &= \Delta w\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-s^2\right)\frac{1}{\Delta w}ds \\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-s^2\right)ds\end{align}

Both integration are independent of $\Delta w$. Therefore $$\lim_{\Delta w \to 0+}\int_{-\pi/\Delta w}^{\pi/\Delta w}f(\Delta w, t) dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp\left(-s^2\right)ds \neq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-s^2\right)ds = \lim_{\Delta w \to 0+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta w, t) dt $$

Comment: Ok, interesting. But the very last equality doesn't hold. Adding the $\lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+}$ is not justified. If it was, it would imply that  $$  \lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\Delta \omega,t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\Delta \omega,t) dt$$ i.e. $$\lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Delta \omega \exp(-(t\Delta\omega)^2)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \Delta \omega \exp(-(t\Delta\omega)^2)dt$$.

Comment: Now, pulling the limit inside the integral: $$ \lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+} \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)} = \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)} $$ Applying L'Hôpital on the LHS yields  $$  \frac{1}{2\Delta\omega t^2\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)} = \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)} $$   or, after some simplifying: $$2t^2 =(\Delta \omega)^2$$ However, $\Delta \omega$ and $t$ are independent variables and therefore the equality cannot hold.

Comment: For some context, the very first equation in my original post is the only missing link in my derivation of the Fourier transform. If it holds, the proof comes together. So $t$ corresponds to continuous time while $\Delta \omega$ is the base angular frequency in the Fourier series of a periodic signal.

Comment: @fosheimdet $$\lim_{\Delta w \to 0+} \exp((t\Delta w)^2) = 1 \neq 0$$ so you cannot applying L'Hospital in that way. Moreover I cannot see why the following should holds, $$\lim_{\Delta \omega \to 0^+} \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)} = \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)}$$ in two respects: (1) Why these integrands should be same? (2) $\lim_{\Delta \omega \to 0^+} \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)} = 0$, not $ \frac{\Delta \omega}{\exp((t\Delta\omega)^2)}$

Comment: sera, you're right. I was wrong to apply L' Hôpital, however my point still stands. I'll address your queries in order: (1) In your original answer, in the very last equation, you have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-s^2)ds = \lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta \omega, t) dt (i)$$ However, this doesn't follow from the calculations above that equation. From your above calculations you can only stat that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-s^2)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta \omega, t) dt $$

Comment: And so if for that inequality to hold, you must have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-s^2)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta \omega, t) dt  = \lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta \omega, t) dt $$ The integral can be approximated as the limit of a sum (e.g. Riemann sum) in which you can switch the order of the two limits and pull the $\Delta \omega$ limit inside the sum. That's my heuristic explanation for pulling the limit inside the integral and thus why the integrands should be the same.

Comment: 2) Yes, agreed. And from this we get: $$f(\Delta \omega, t) \neq \lim_{\Delta \omega \to 0^+} f(\Delta \omega, t) $$ and thus $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-s^2)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta \omega, t) dt  \neq \lim_{\Delta \omega->0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\Delta \omega, t) dt $$ Therefore, you cannot conclude that $$\lim_{\Delta \omega \to 0^+} \int_{-\pi/\Delta \omega}^{\pi/\Delta \omega} f(\Delta \omega, t) dt \neq \lim_{\Delta \omega \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\Delta \omega, t) dt$$